# How to use Static Ethernet ip and Wi-Fi at the same time in raspberry pi 3b+

Tags: linux, networking, raspberry-pi3

I have a problem with raspberry pi that when I enter static ip Ethernet in settings, my WiFi does not work.
this is /etc/dhcpcd.conf configuration:

```
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.1.27/24
static routers=192.168.1.1
static domain_name_servers=
static domain_search=
```

I'm manually connected to my wifi mobile phone.When i set my network configuration to dhcp my wifi problem is solved

Answer (score -1):

I believe the "metric" parameter is what you're looking for:

```
interface eth0
metric 300

interface wlan0
metric 200
```

Lowest number has priority.